# How to pass a variable from actions to component

Tags: reactjs, object, action

Hooray I have my API answer console logged in my action:

```
function listTemplates(specs) {
    const payload = templateList.post(specs);
    return dispatch => dispatch({ ...types.GET_TEMPLATES, payload });
}

function apiResponse(response) {
    const res = response;
    console.log(res);
}

const actions = {
    listTemplates,
    apiResponse,
};
```

Wait but how do I send it to my component to be processed and displayed?

UPDATE :

I have followed a bit at the end of this guide : http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components

and adapted it to my (more complete (applyMiddleware + Store.jsx as a seperate file)) app setup.

So no I have store available everywhere.

this is my GetTemplate.jsx Reducer :

```
import EventTypes from '../EventTypes';
import actions from '../../Components/Menu/actions';

const initialState = {
    templates: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case EventTypes.GET_TEMPLATES_FULFILLED.type:
            const returnValue = action.payload.body().data();
            actions.apiResponse(returnValue);
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

what am I missing? I don't really understand how this all works.

What do I need in my template list component?

Comment: are you using redux ?

Comment: Handle the action in a [reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html), and [use the `connect` function from react-redux to pull the data from the store into your component](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components).

Comment: yes @tariq I am using redux :)

Comment: @Renée I am currently using the `connect` function could you provide me with an example as an answer please?

Comment: @Renée I'm still perplexed `case EventTypes.GET_TEMPLATES_FULFILLED.type:` in a reducer is already how I got the API answer in the first place I don't see how I can further use reducers in this case.

Comment: Oh, I see now—one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    case EventTypes.GET_TEMPLATES_FULFILLED.type:
        const returnValue = action.payload.body().data();
        actions.apiResponse(returnValue); // ← ←
        return state;
```

Redux reducers should return new state, not call other actions. Use something like:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { templates: returnValue })
```

Now Redux will save that data in its store. Then, using the [`connect` function from react-redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components), you can select that data from the store and use it in your component.

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return { templates: state.templates }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TemplatesComponent)
```